# Problema con UTF_8

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

Buen día, mi problema es el siguiente, Php me lanza el siguiente Warning

> Warning: utf8_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in.

Ya revisé mi código y tengo declarado el characterSet de éste modo `"CharacterSet" => "UTF-8"` Si lo borro no me arroja resultados, la parte de código dónde me lanza el error es la siguiente

```
<?php 
            //imprime resultados codificados a utf8 en caso de no haber resultados no hace nada
            if($hay){
                while($result = sqlsrv_fetch_object($results)) {
                    echo "<tr>";
                        foreach ($result as $col) {
                            echo "<td>". utf8_decode($col) ."</td>";
                        }
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
            }
             ?>
```

Todo después de una consulta que me arroja resultados parciales, ahora ya revisé, hice `var_dump` y obtuve el `gettype` de `$col` y me di cuenta (como en la consulta incluye un campo tipo Datatime) que la fecha es la que de alguna manera no convierte y me causa éste warning, imprimiendo casi todos los datos a excepción de la fecha.

¿Alguien sabrá qué puedo hacer para resolver el warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El warning dice literalmente que la función `utf8_decode` espera recibir una cadena de caracteres y le estás pasando un objeto.

Por la manera en que está escrito tu código, ya que la variable `$col` va cambiando de tipo según el resultado obtenido, tienes estas dos alternativas:

## aplicar un [molde de tipo](http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.type-juggling.php)

La idea básica es:

```
$myText = (string)$myVar;
```

Así, podría quedar:

```
                        foreach ($result as $col) {
                            $txt = (string)$col;
                            echo "<td>". utf8_decode($txt) ."</td>";
                        }
```

## concatenar

PHP forzará la variable a ser un `string` si le concatenas otra cadena, por ejemplo:

```
$txt = $myVar . " "
```

Así, podrías dejar:

```
                        foreach ($result as $col) {
                            echo "<td>". utf8_decode($col." ") ."</td>";
                        }
```

## DateTime

Luego del comentario del OP, me he dado cuenta que justamente esto fallará con DateTime, no tengo forma de probarlo ahora, pero esto debiera funcionar:

```
foreach ($result as $col) {
    if ($col instanceof DateTime) {
      $txt = $col->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    } else {
      $txt = (string)$col;
    }
    echo "<td>". utf8_decode($txt) ."</td>";
}
```

Comment: Genial, gracias por eso, aunque ahora me sale 

`Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string`

Supongo debo transformar el format o qué puedo hacer?

Comment: @Augustoock he editado la respuesta para incluir el caso de DateTime.

Comment: Sip así la matienes de forma génerica para campos escalares  y DateTime, pero el resto de compuestos...http://us.php.net/manual/es/language.types.php aún así creo que estas cosas es mejor ponerlas de forma explícita, como puse más abajo (a parte de que seguro que quiere elegir dónde va cada dato y el título de cada columna.

Comment: Genial ha funcionado @jachguate muchas gracias, ya quedo funcionando a todo :), también me pareció interesante lo que pusiste Ricardo, gracias por ayudar

Answer (score 1):

Estás intentando imprimir todos los campos de un registro de forma genérica. Si no es eso lo que buscas, tal vez deberías especificarlos uno a uno:

```
<?php
   if($hay)
   {
     while($result = sqlsrv_fetch_object($results)) 
     {
        echo "<tr><td>".
                       $result->campo1."</td><td>". 
                       $result->campofecha->format('Y-m-d H:i:s').
            "</td></tr>";            
     }
   }
?>
```

De esta forma no debería saltarte ningún error.

Recuerda también consultar la [página del manual](http://php.net/manual/es/function.sqlsrv-fetch-object.php) Ahí te indica que los métodos del objeto devuelto se corresponden con los nombres de los campos y demás cosas necesarias para usarla.

Suerte ;-)